# Does the Apple Magic Mouse work with only one AA battery?

Tags: battery, magic-mouse

I have a Microsoft Intellimouse Explorer mouse and it works with either one or two batteries. It's nice because using only one battery makes it considerably lighter. I was wondering if this is possible with the Magic Mouse as well. Anyone willing to try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't! But it ***may*** be adapted to do so... Would involve some nifty craftsmanship though.

Check the teardown here: http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Magic-Mouse/1240/1
If you look at the pictures of the battery compartment, you'll see that they aren't alligned in series but parallel. Which means it uses 1.5 Volts. (which one battery should also be able to provide) Perhaps if you solder the two contacts at the bottom of the compartment on this picture together, it will work... Would take trial and error though.

It probably won't do performance much good though... Could cause loss of signal since it's wireless or unresponsiveness.

As digitxp mentioned, you could also put in a paperclip... That also works.. it just wouldn't be as elegant a solution...

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1):

You can using a paperclip (just shape it so it touches both of the terminals and tape it down), but I know that doing that for a lightbulb will make it much dimmer, so I assume that the Magic Mouse would either not work (from some Apple lockdown), feel unresponsive (not enough power to transmit a strong signal), or short-circuit.

Comment: As I started reading this, I was getting ready to try it out, but the last word made me stop. Has anyone else gone ahead with this? I don't wanna fry my brand new Magic Mouse!